# How to iterate through the Facebook User data using the flutter_facebook_auth package

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, iterator, facebook-authentication

I'm successfully logging into Facebook with Flutter using the flutter_facebook_auth package and now I'm having trouble getting my user profile info in the getUserData method map.  Here is my code....

```
var userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
Map<String, dynamic> _userData;
_userData = userData;
var info = _userData['items'];

String facebookName;

for (var items in info) {
  Map myMap = items; //store each map
  var name = (myMap['name'] as Map).toString();
  facebookName = name;
}
```

When trying to print facebookName, I get the following error...

> The getter 'iterator' was called on null.

I'm not sure exactly where I'm getting this wrong.  Please help!

Printing _userData give the following desired map...

flutter: {email: , id: , picture: {data: {is_silhouette: false, height: 122, url: , width: 200}}, name: Charles Cleveland Jr.}

Comment: Can you log your `_userData` variable ?

Comment: The info variable is null

Comment: _userData is the correct map with my name, email, and an imbedded data map for user pictures

Comment: Post it's content boss

Comment: If there are sensitive data you can change them to fake ones

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the name, you can proceed as following

```
String facebookName;
_userData.forEach((key, value) {
  if ("name" == key) facebookName = value;
});
print(facebookName);
```